# XcodeでChartsを活用する方法

Tags: xcode

プログラミング初心者です。

Xcodeで円グラフを取り扱いと考えておりましたところ、
「Chartsというものを活用すればなんとなくできそう」という考えに至りました。

以下のリンクの手順通りにしようと思ったのですが...

[【Swift】円グラフを描画する（Charts）](https://www.hfoasi8fje3.work/entry/2019/03/04/213142)

手順1で詰まりました。
Chartsをインストール??するにはどのような手順が必要なのでしょうか。

初心者でありますので、手順を示していただけるとありがたいです。
どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Comment: リンク先の記事は、Xcodeでゼロから新規のプロジェクトを作成したり、CocoaPodsでそのプロジェクトに外部ライブラリーを追加したり、なんて経験のある人を対象に、自明の部分を端折って書かれているようです。まだ、CocoaPodsを使ったことがないのであれば「CocoaPods 使い方」あたりで検索すると、かなり詳しく手順を解説したサイトが見つかります。まずはそこら辺のサイトをいくつか覗いてみて、CocoaPodsを導入して基本的な使い方をマスターしてから、再度リンク先の記事を読んでみると良いでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。「CocoaPods 使い方」と、ググるところからやってみます。